# Google Analytics utmz cookie overwritten to "Direct" on ecommerce confirmation page

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, e-commerce

I've seen this issue discussed, but haven't seen a very clear answer as of yet.

I'm noticing that in GA, and using FireCookie, that on the confirmation page of my clien'ts ecommerce booking engine, the utmz cookie is being set to "Direct" regardless of how the user initially got the page.  Cross domain tracking is set up, so the utmz is tracked correctly from www.domain1.com to www.bookingengine.com up until the confirmation page of the booking engine where the ecommerce code is.  All of the ecommerce information is being recorded correctly in GA - so I'm fairly certain that part is set correctly.  The GA coding on the confirmation page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            try {
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
            pageTracker._initData();
            pageTracker._setDomainName("none");
            pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
            pageTracker._trackPageview("funnel_G1/step5.html");
```

The coding on all previous steps of the www.bookingengine.com is all the same (except, obviously for the `pageTracker._trackPageview();`

I've previously read that `pageTracker._setAllowHash(false);` might have something to do with this, but I thought it was deprecated so it shouldn't really be affecting anything.  But, could it still affect the tracking in regards to the utmz cookie?

As a reference, we also connect to a second, different booking engine depending on options selected in the form, www.bookingengine2.com, and this does have the `pageTracker._setAllowHash(false);` code on it - and holds the utmz code through the entire booking process, even on the confirmation page.

So, did I just answer my own question? Or is there something else going on here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: About : pageTracker._initData();
It is depecrated and if used it should be called AFTER the latest configuration line, there it is called first
I would suggest to remove this line.


trackPageview should happen BEFORE the transaction is built and sent